# Help with simple C-code for square wave pulse

Tags: pic

I am not sure why I must change it.. or edit it...???
some people seem to understand what I typed up..??
please can the WORRIED persons please write up.. and tell me what I have to change... or edit
.???
thanks..

I need to know how to write a simple routine in C to switch two I/O ports, namely A1 and A2 on a PIC16LF88 processor so that I can generate a square wave pulse of 40 kHz.

This means: A1 on, A2 off, hold this state for 12.5 usec then switch A1 off. A2 on, hold for 12.5 usec then loop back to top
Do this for say any number of times, say from a variable which could have 5 or 20 or 10, so that the loop repeats for that number of times.

I have a program called Flowcode 9.
I use Flocode for all my normal work, but this time Flowcode cannot perform the function.  Inside an icon in Flowcode called C-code, one can enter C-code which will then compile into the final hex file.
What I would like is ask someone who uses C-code normally to help me create the C-code to switch the two ports A1 and A2 on this PIC16LF88 chip. The reason is I have inherited some PCBs with this hardware config: Two 40 kHz transducers and the transmit unit is connected to ports A1 and A2. Switching them inside Flowcode is too slow with an 8 MHz clock,  so obviously pure C-code must be used.

I am prepared to share the Flowcode with a willing person so that we may accomplish this project needs.

Comment: This would be a very simple "C" program for a PIC. Here is code for a 100 kHz square wave using a PIC16C84 with a 4 MHz clock. Very similar code will work on a PIC16LF88. What may be more important is how you will design a circuit to drive the transducers. https://pic-microcontroller.com/100khz-square-wave-generator-using-pic16c84/. Please provide your best effort to draw up a schematic, and post your attempt at coding. I don't know how FLOWCODE can help.

Comment: Please run your text though a word processor

Comment: Hi Larry; you use ".." and "..." a lot. I'm not a native English speaker myself, so this makes it twice as hard to read – please use *not a single* of these in your question. I really can't fully follow what you're writing. There's sentences, which end in a period ("."), and there's clauses that get divided by a comma (","), but stringing together partial sentences with ellipses makes it impossible to mentally structure this. And it's not our job: **You** need to structure your text to make it understandable, and that means defining clear sentences, not a "stream of consciousness" like this.

Comment: Don't worry about writing *perfect* English, though. Just make it *structured*. An engineer thinks in logical conclusions, statements and questions. A good engineering question hence looks like "I have XYZ and ABC. I used them to form a system DEF by doing GHI, which results in JKL. Because JKL is MNO, I need to solve PQR. How do I do that without STU? I've tried VWX, but it led to YZ.", and **not** "This means... A.. and B.. hold.. something.. I HAVE A CODE..."

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to use a timer for this situation.

Here is some pseudo code for this:

```
TIMERISR:
   if flag:
      SetPinA false
      SetPinB true
      flag = false;
      counter--
   else:
      SetPinA true
      SetPinB false
      flag = true;

   if counter == 0:
      DisableTimerIsr
      SetPinA false 
      SetPinB true

ConfigTimer(NumberOfSquareWaves):
    if counter != 0:
        return //Blocks access while pulse train active.
    SetTimerOverFlowFal: 80kHz
    counter = NumberOfSquareWaves
    EnableISRandStartTimer
    SetPinA false 
    SetPinB true
```

In essence it enables a timer with x2 the desired squarewave frequency.
Based on a flag it switches the pin on or off.
It does that for a number of cycles configure by the user.

You can google how to implement the require C-Code. Its not that complicated.
In your flowplane you can call the "ConfigTimer(NumberOfPulses):" routine every time you want to generate a pulse-train.

The actual pulse generation within "TIMERISR:" than does not need any more intervention from main-code.